# Hom much memory does a Jquery Element Reference Take Up?

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, dom

If I have a plugin that makes reference to the same JQuery objects constantly I figure I should cache the reference.

I was wondering if anyone knew off hand **how much memory a jquery reference takes up?**

Also I do understand that the price of the JQuery lookup far exeeds the price of the reference itself.

```
$('sameElement')
```

vs

```
this.sameElement = $('sameElement'); 
this.sameElement
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It'll be the same as any other object reference, plus the memory of any of its *own properties*.

Its own properties are:

- `.length`      Number (64 bit) showing the current elements in the collection
- `.prevObject`  Reference to another jQuery object, which will hold reference to the previous set of elements (can be a memory leak in some cases)
- `.context`     Context element from which the selection was made
- `.selector`    Your selector string

Comment: In addition, if you run any plugins on your jQuery object, they can themselves hold references to arbitrary amounts of memory.

Comment: A jQuery instance internally stores an array with all elements of its collection, i.e. an object reference for each element. This array, which is probably the most memory-consuming by far, should be added to the answer.